# How to correctly pass objects from the controller to the view in PHP?

Tags: php, templates, crud

For learning purposes, I built a very simple MVC-pattern. In order learn how to display the content of a specific database table in the view, I wrote a simple read-function in my **model (m_crud.php)** as so:

```
<?php

class Crud{

    private $Database;
    private $db_table = 'products';

    function __construct()
    {
        global $Database;
        $this->Database = $Database;
    }


    // READ (SELECT)

    public function read(){

        $query="SELECT * FROM $this->db_table";

        $result= $this->Database->query($query);

        $num_result=$result->num_rows;


        if($num_result>0){
            while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){

                $this->data[]=$rows;

                //print_r($rows);       
            }

            return $this->data;
        }       
    }
}
```

The database details are stored in **init.php**, where the CRUD-object is initiated as well:

```
<?php

// Connect to database

$server = 'localhost';
$user   = 'root';
$pass   = 'MyPassword';
$db     = 'MyDatabase;

$Database = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);


// Error reporting

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


// Include objects

include('app/models/m_crud.php');
include('app/models/m_template.php');


// Create Objects

$Crud = new Crud(); // Creates an instance of the CRUD Class


// Start session

session_start();
```

My **controller** (that's the part where I am stuck) looks as follows:

```
<?php
include('app/init.php');

$Template->load('app/views/v_members.php');

$obj = $Crud->read();

    if ( ! empty($obj))
    {

    // Pass product data to view
    // How do you correctly pass the object data to the view?


    }
```

At the moment, I instantiate the CRUD-object within the view to display the content ofy my 'products'-table, which works, but effectively breaks the MVC pattern:

```
<?php include("includes/private_header.php"); ?>

<div id="content">

<?php
$obj=new Crud;
$obj->read();
?>

<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <th width="16" scope="row">ID</th>
    <td width="95">Category</td>
    <td width="95">Name</td>
    <td width="140">Description</td>
    <td width="104">Price</td>
    <td width="71">Image</td>
    <td>action</td>
  </tr>  

<?php
foreach($obj->data as $val){
    extract($val);

    ?>
    <tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $category_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $price; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $image; ?></td>
     <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">edit</a>|<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    <?php
}

?>
</table>


</div>

<?php include("includes/private_footer.php"); ?>
```

How can I pass the CRUD-object from controller to the view in order to clean up the view?

Answer (score 0):

Set the variables echoed in your view in the if block of your controller. Assuming that "$Template->load('app/views/v_members.php');" calls your view, you then place that after the if block. Otherwise, you could include your controller at the top of your view script.

```
$obj = $Crud->read();

if ( ! empty($obj))
{

foreach($obj->data as $val){
 extract($val);
}


}
//If your Template->load function is calling the view
$Template->load('app/views/v_members.php');
```

Comment: And how do I pass the variables, which I echo in the controller, to the view?